# How To Skip Precompilation of Already Minified Javascript and Still Retain the Require Sequence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4, restangular

I'm using Restangular with Rails 4, and I wish to tell rails to skip precompiling Restangular as I'm using the official minified version which doesn't mangle the variable names to prevent problems with Angular dependency injection.

Here's my `application.js.coffee`:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require unstable/angular
#= require underscore
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./vendor
#= require_tree ./configs
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./directives
#= require_tree ./filters
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./misc

window.app = angular.module "myApp", ["restangular"]
```

The minified `restangular.min.js` file lives under the "javascripts/vendor" directory. It needs to be loaded after Angular and before all my controllers and models and stuff are loaded.

How can I tell Rails asset pipeline to skip minifying the restangular file and still load it the correct order?

Thanks!

### Edit:

I found the solution and answered my own question.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to exclude a particular file?

Comment: @David: Yes, that is correct. I could just reference the file in my application layout with something like this `<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/restangular.min.js" %>`. The problem is that this file needs to be loaded **after** angular and before everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

I was using [ngmin-rails](https://github.com/jasonm/ngmin-rails) gem to avoid problems with asset pipeline(Uglifier mangle) for my angular code. I never knew that third party libraries like restangular can also go through ngmin-rails. So I added the following line at the top of the pre-minified `restangular.min.js` file and it works like a charm!

`var app = angular.module("myApp");`

BTW, I also removed this line from my application layout html: `<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/restangular.min.js" %>`

Comment: What line did you add? This isn't really a solution to skipping pre-minified files. Glad it worked for you but is it really right answer for your question?

Comment: You are right. My solution does not solve this SO question, but it solved my problem - the real problem which is the reason why I asked this SO question in the first place. I appreciate your effort in trying to help me, and the workaround you suggested, but it isn't really a perfect solution to either this SO question or the problem I'm having. On the other hand, your workaround is pretty close to answering this SO question specifically, so to make up for it, I've upvoted your answer to make your effort worthwhile. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for a solution to this problem -- skipping minification of 3rd party libraries -- but in the meantime:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:mangle => false)
```

Then switch your vendor lib to the unminified [source](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/restangular/latest/restangular.js) and let Rails crunch it until you/we find a better option.

More Uglifier options [here](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried adding `<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/restangular.min.js" %>` after `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in the application layout html. It works in development mode, but in production mode, Rails "Refused to serve file... for its MIME type is text/html" (not the exact error message, but pretty close). It'd be awesome if we can configure Uglifier to only turn off mangle for specific files. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: did you run rake assets:precompile?

Comment: Yes. BTW, here's the exact message for that MIME type error:
`Refused to execute script from 'http://example.com/javascripts/vendor/restangular.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: Fhe file being served to the browser at that URL is probably an HTML error message